# Were the entrails of the victims of the 2000 Ramallah lynching held aloft by mob members?

Tags: israel, terrorism, palestine

In the [2000 Ramallah lynching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Ramallah_lynching) two Israeli reservists were killed and their bodies mutilated.

**Warning: The images linked below are disturbing and not safe for work.**

An image included in a [2020 Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-photos-that-Palestine-does-not-want-the-world-to-see) purports to shows a scene from the lynching, with two men in a mob clutching entrails.

The same image appears in [2010](https://freeisraelnow.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/10-years-to-ramallah-lynch-october-2000-animalism/) and [2011](https://astuteblogger.blogspot.com/2011/01/never-forget-mozlem-cannibals-of.html) blog posts.

Were the entrails of the victims held up by mob members?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. This image has been circulated with a claim that it is from that particular incident, i couldn't find an original source for it, so I am questioning whether the particulars occurred and whether the photo is indeed of that event.

Answer (score 4):

## *"display the entrails of the victims"*

The 2000 Ramallah lynching happened on Oct 12, 2000, after two dozen Palestinian minors were killed and dozens of adults, and settlers from Halamish beat and ran over Issam Hamad and dumped his body. Depending on who you ask, the lynching started

- when two confused IDF officers were apprehended after accidentally driving unescorted into Ramallah in the midst of an uprising (Second Intifada) between the Palestinians and Israeli occupiers
- when [two IDF agents on an undercover mission](https://www.cnn.com/2000/WORLD/meast/10/14/israel.tm.tm/) were apprehended.

The two officers were subsequently detained by the PLO before thousands amassed at the place of detainment, but the police were ["incapable of restraining" the mob](https://www.cnn.com/2000/WORLD/meast/10/14/israel.tm.tm/) and the mob took advantage of the situation. Thirteen Palestinians were injured trying to stop the lynching.

The (racist) source [think-israel.org](http://www.think-israel.org/freerepublic.octoberramallahlynch.html) (which uses the bizarre term "Arab-Islamic animalism") claims this comes from an article called [This is the Enemy](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/332320) which was published by Israel National News, whose Hebrew outlet is called [Arutz Sheva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arutz_Sheva). That article has a claim that says,

> Ramallah or Fallujah savages dancing with human entrails.

But it does not reproduce the image. I don't find the image to be notable. The claim that they "danced with human entrails" is otherwise unsubstantiated (there is no source for it). We can be sure that the purported author, [Nissan Ratzlav-Katz](https://www.linkedin.com/in/nissan-ratzlav-katz-4270a05/details/experience/) lists his position as an Opinion Editor at [Arutz Sheva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arutz_Sheva) at the time, so it's likely this is his work. But, it's not clear whose opinion he was reporting, or whether or not it was his own.

However, [Jpost which is generally very right-wing (not favorable to Palestinians) describes the events as](https://www.jpost.com/israel-news/remembering-the-ramallah-lynching-20-years-later-645964) (note: lacks any claims to the "display of entrails" as shown in the picture linked),

> The IDF reservists were murdered by the crowd via beatings and stabbings, with one Italian news outlet later capturing the infamous photo Aziz Salha raising his blood-soaked hands to the cheering crowd. The reservists' **bodies were then thrown out the window, mutilated and set on fire. The bodies were then dragged to Al-Manara Square in the city center.**

The [Times of Israel also doesn't reproduce the claim, but summarizes the events with an interview](https://www.timesofisrael.com/we-were-in-a-craze-to-see-blood/),

> “**We were in a craze to see blood.** I entered the room… I saw an Israeli soldier sprawled on the floor in front of the door,” said 32-year-old Aziz Salha, one of the participants in the attack. “I came closer to him and saw a knife lodged in his back, near his right shoulder. I removed the knife and stabbed him in the back two or three times… while others in the room continued to kick him. I put my hand over his mouth and the other on his shoulder, in order to strangle him.”

Aziz Salha was convicted of murder and sentenced to life.

At the point there is a lynching, and you have testimony from the perpetrator that they "were in a craze to see blood" all bets are off. I would judge the claim to be somewhat likely, but unevidenced.